# Is there a way to add code to an infinite z80 assembly loop?

Tags: calculator, infinite-loop, texas-instruments, ti-basic, z80

A while ago, I asked what the fastest infinite loop was on a TI-84. One of the answers I got involved using an assembly infinite loop with this code:

```
AsmPrgm
18FE
```

However, this is a bit impractical, because it can only be exited with the reset button and doesnt run anything inside it.

Is there a way to put TI-Basic code inside of this loop and/or make it exit conditionally?

Here is the link to the original question and answer:
[What is the fastest infinite loop in TI-84+ Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028809/what-is-the-fastest-infinite-loop-in-ti-84-basic/42237374#42237374)

Comment: A pure to TI-BASIC solution would be to use a Repeat or While loop. I believe we need more information on what you want to do with the loop to offer better answers. Also, technically a "jp" loop would be faster, but it would require knowing the address. For example C3959D is 10cc versus 12cc for 18FE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely make assembly programs exit conditionally. The command `C9` is return, so if you have a program consisting of only `AsmPrgmC9`, running it as an assembly program will have it instantly finish (it will look the same as running a program with nothing in it). If you want to end the loop when some condition is met, then you'll need to start learning assembly as the answer will widely vary on what that condition is and what OS version/calculator you're using.

Answer (score 4):

$18FE is jr -2, which loops two bytes backwards, in on itself. You'll want the additional logic to come after the start of the loop to let you escape (i.e. checking for button presses), then just have it loop back to that label. To do that, you'd need to adjust the $FE value, as that's the distance to jump. It's a signed 8-bit value, so make sure you get all your conditional code in, then branch back depending on the number of bytes you've used.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your original (linked) question, jr $ is not the fastest loop possible on Z80, as the fastest one is jp $ (actually jp (hl)), where $ denotes the address of the current instruction. 
The fastest exitable loop could be done in three ways, depending on what is your definition of 'loop' is and how the loop should be exited:

1. Use the interrupts to quit abovementioned loop: in this case, you should unwind stack in the interrupt (remove return address) and jump elsewhere.
2. Use the loop like this:

​

```
IN reg,(C)
JP cc,$-2
```

where IN reg,(C) command also sets S (sign), Z (zero) and P/V (parity) flags depending on the value read from port and JP cc uses one of those flags to continue the loop or leave it.

3. Use the `HALT` and exit it naturally with the interrupt.

It is known that Z80 executes `HALT` by continuously fetching the same byte following `HALT` instruction from the memory, then ignoring it and doing that until the interrupt is caught. This behaviour could be described as looping until the interrupt is caught. The root cause for such behaviour is that Z80 naturally does DRAM refresh every opcode fetch and this way the refresh is kept during `HALT` execution.

Comment: Fastest loop is "LD HL,$+3; JP (HL)".  With some very careful setup you could make "IN L,(C); JP (HL)" work.

Comment: Of course, writing your own interrupt sequence is a bit tricky on TI-84 calculators. You have to use IM 2, but the byte sent in is completely random (well, some calculators it isn't, but you should treat it as random), so you need to set an entire 257 byte sequence to all the same byte where your interrupt code is.

Comment: Oh yeah, exactly, jp (hl)! How could I... :) I dared to update my answer a bit.